# multiplying the integrands in an inequality of integrals with same limits

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, improper-integrals, integral-inequality

I am trying to find rigorous justification for the following.

If we have the following inequality
$$
\int_{X}^{\infty}u(x)\mbox{d}x \le 
\int_{X}^{\infty}v(x)\mbox{d}x
$$
If we now multiply both sides with $\exp(-k(x))$ as in 
$$
\int_{X}^{\infty}\exp(-k(x))u(x)\mbox{d}x \le 
\int_{X}^{\infty}\exp(-k(x))v(x)\mbox{d}x
$$
then the inequality is preserved.

My initial thoughts were to collect the terms
$$
0 \le 
\int_{X}^{\infty}(v(x) - u(x))\mbox{d}x
$$
and the then try use integration by parts after multiplying with $\exp(-k(x))$ to show the RHS will be satisfy the inequality, but that lead me to circular kind of argument. Also i do not know if $v(x)$ is differentiable.

How can this be rigorously justified ? If these conditions do not suffice, what additional conditions are minimally needed so this will hold.

Thank you

Comment: It is not true. I have posted an answer. But I have question, do you mean that the inequality holds for all $X$ or what?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking it holds for all $X$. I have just seen your answer, I did have a follow up question, which is under what additional conditions on $u$ $v$ and $k$ will it hold ?

Comment: It holds for example if $0\le u(x)\le v(x)$ for all $X\le x\le\infty$. $k$ may be then arbitrary real function of $x$.

Comment: @user355705 thank you that is very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is not true as it is stated at this moment.** Take $u(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$ and $v(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[1,3]}$. It is clear that it satisfies the condition mentioned. Now take $k(x)=x$ and $X=0$ to get:
\begin{align}
I:=\int_0^\infty \exp(-x)u(x)\,dx=1-e^{-1}
\end{align}
while:
\begin{align}
J:=\int^\infty_0 \exp(-x)v(x)\,dx=e^{-1}-e^{-3}
\end{align}
Since $2e^{-1}<1$, we have $e^{-1}<1-e^{-1}$. Hence $e^{-1}-e^{-3}<1-e^{-1}$ and that implies $J<I$.

Comment: You mention that it is not true as it is stated. How would you restate so it is correct. I think it is the use of the indicator functions which is the loop hole in my statement. No ?

Comment: @ComicBookGuy even without indicator functions you can come up with such example. Just try to make the indicator function continuous by letting let it go down from $1$ to $0$ in the endpoints quickly.  Now you have an example with $u,v$ and $k$ continuous and possibly differentiable.  One can construct such function. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: what if an additionally we could say that $u$ and $v$ are strictly non negative and non indicator function

Comment: @ComicBookGuy if you construct the functions I just told you about, you get a nonnegative function which is continuous. It is not  an indicator function either. So....

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

For an intuitive explanation of a counterexample: suppose $k(x)$ is zero "most of the time", so the inequality is unchanged, but then $k(x)$ happens to be very large for values of $x$ where $u(x)$ is zero, but it so happens that $v(x)$ is very large and negative.

Then $\int e^{-k(x)} v(x)$ will be much smaller, but $\int e^{-k(x)} u(x)$ would be unchanged, which can ruin the inequality.